# what does attempting to create use_block_in_frame mean

Tags: ios

I've seen this question posted before but all answers given where fixes to specific code errors that were posted.

I want to know what does "attempting to create use_block_in_frame" actually mean and what can generally be the cause of it.

Comment: I can't say for certain what it means, but here is the code that produces it - http://opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-231/src/gdb/varobj.c - and here is the change log where USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME gets added - http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-186.1/src/gdb/ChangeLog

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning from the debugger itself that it could not create an info struct for a particular object. Basically it's fallout from a previous error.

It's probably a red herring. I'd suggest looking at errors referring to your code (note this one is a warning only) that happened before this and work from there. Figuring out the particulars of this warning is unlikely to help.